# Why does BWF Anglicise player name order in some, but not all, relevant languages?

Tags: badminton

I just watched a Malaysia Masters men’s doubles quarter final between a Chinese pair and a Japanese pair, and at the end of the match, something occurred to me which I hadn’t noticed before.

The banner on the screen showing the final results with the players’ full names showed them thus:

> Takuro **HOKI** / Yugo **KOBAYASHI**
> **LIANG** Wei Keng / **WANG** Chang

The [match page on the BWF website](https://match-centre.bwfbadminton.com/4440/match/185) shows them the same way. The bold, uppercase name is the surname/family name, so they are shown in opposite orders: the Chinese players are shown in the format `FAMILY-NAME given-name`, while the Japanese players are shown in the format `given-name FAMILY-NAME`.

Now, in both Chinese and Japanese, the family name comes first: the native forms of their names are:

- **保木**卓朗 ***HOKI** Takurō*
- **小林**優吾 ***KOBAYASHI** Yūgo*
- **梁**伟铿 ***LIÁNG** Wěikēng*
- **王**昶 ***WÁNG** Chǎng*

But in BWF terms, the first two are switched, while the last two are maintained as natively.

This seems to be a general thing: Chinese (and Korean) names are given in the indigenous order, family name first,<sup>1</sup> while Japanese names are switched to the English order with the given name first.

To me, there are two equally valid ways of navigating the complicated issue of names:

1. Always write each player’s name in the order they themselves use
2. Standardise all names to the format used in the official tournament language (English)

The chosen tactic of mixing 1 and 2 the way BWF seems to do currently makes very little sense to me.

**So why is this the tactic chosen?** Are they perhaps basing it on some sort of official Anglicising standard in each country? Did someone just arbitrarily choose at some point and it stuck?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The same appears to be the case for [Telugu names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_names) such as ***PUSARLA** V. Sindhu*, but Indian names are horribly complicated and I don’t know much about them, so let’s ignore that. There also seem to be some cases where BWF have completely messed up, like [Thinaah Muralitharan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinaah_Muralitharan), whose name is given as “[**THINAAH** Muralitharan](https://bwfworldtour.bwfbadminton.com/player/68628/thinaah-muralitharan)”, although her Wikipedia page makes it clear that it’s Muralitharan which is the family name.</sup>

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yeah, I remember that one, and while it’s amusing, it’s also defeatist to the point where I always feel like I want to add “41. People exist; 42. The universe exists”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When players are entered into the system by the national federation, there is a [boolean flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type), internally called `AsianName` (this is an internal ID selected by programers, don't interpret too much into it). If that flag is set, then the family name is shown first.

So it's up to the national federation (and potentially their club or regional sub-bureaucracies) to correctly enter their player names.
Until 2019, the [Japanese standard was Givenname FAMILYNAME](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-japan-names-idUSKCN1VR1LE) in English, even outside of sports, so that's what the Japanese badminton federation used when registering HOKI Takurō in 2011.

The national federation (on its own volition or upon request from a player, club, or state federation) can change names and set or unset the `AsianName` flag.

Sometimes, a mistake in some bureaucracy can also cause the `AsianName` flag to be set although the name is already anglicized.